# Add new Attributes with Add more button

Tags: attributes, products, attribute-set, custom-attributes

Hi I need to create a new attribute set in Products in which will contain a text area and an Image. How do I make it have an Add more button in which it will create another set of text area and image field? Thanks!

EDIT: I need to create a slider in which the contents will be coming from the backend. I need to have a text area for the description and an Image field to upload the Image for slider. The content manager should be able to upload as many as he wants so I cannot just create those attributes there hence I need to have some sort of an "Add more" button. (I need to create something like the uploading of images on products in where when you click "Upload Files" it will create another set of fields.)

Comment: @boinxFlafs please explain question i not understand it....

Comment: @AshvinMonpara edited the question sir.